# Vue 3 with vue3-cookies sets same cookies to different locations on variable routes

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vuex, vuejs3, vue-cookies

I loading saved in cookies user authorization data when my Vue 3 application mount.
Data in json format like Jwt and Refresh tokens & something user data.

I have setup like:

**main.js:**

```
import VueCookies from 'vue3-cookies'
...
app.use(VueCookies, {
    expireTimes: "365d",
    path: "/"
})
```

In (vuex) store: **auth.module.js:**

I have things like this:

```
import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies"
...
// in getters
const auth = cookies.get('auth')
// and in mutations
cookies.set('auth', auth)
```

And in router I have:

```
const routes = [
...
{
    path: '/user/:id',
    name: 'user',
    props: true,
    component: () => import('@/views/UserView.vue'),
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        availableRoles: [ "Admin" ]
    }
},
...
]
...
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})
```

**So, the problem is, that when I load the location like:**

```
https://[url]/user/new
```

Or

```
https://[url]/user/1
```

I got duplicated cookies.
[image]
[image]
[image]

First **auth** cookie path is `/user` and its empty.
Second **auth** cookie path is `/` and it's ok.

Problem appears only on this route, and IDN why...

Seems like strange bug, do you have same issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I going to route like:

```
<router-link to=`/user/{user.id}`>
```

Then issue occurs.
But, If I going to route like:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { id: String(user?.id) } }">
```

That's fine.
Strange behavior.